# PHP/jQuery chat plugin

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, zend-framework, chat

I want to implement a chat option on website in which any register user can join. This chat option will be public and any one can see chat but only selected users can send messages on chat. There is no any option to chat separately between two users. I am working on PHP, Zend , javascript and jQuery.

Something like this: http://www.thecricket-tv.com/p/channel-1.html

Is it possible. What is the best plugin that fit my need.

It may be subjected but I need this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a simple Facebook/Gmail like chat jQuery plugin i've used.  It's decent.  Uses jQuery, PHP, and MySQL

[jQuery Chat Module](http://anantgarg.com/2009/05/13/gmail-facebook-style-jquery-chat/)

As far as group chat plugin goes, here is another one that is more in the ball park of what you are looking for, but you'll probabaly have to tweak it abit.  Uses jQuery, php, and MySQL as well:

[Chat 2](http://css-tricks.com/chat2/)

Hopefully between these two it'll get you a kick start on your project.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I was searching:

http://chatango.com/

Answer (score 2):

Here is multiuser chat system that supports both group discussions and private chats.  http://amiadogroup.github.com/candy

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best option out there:

http://www.arrowchat.com